# Windows 8 on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, windows, jailbreak, android

I was just watching the [Windows 8 keynote](http://buildwindows.com/) and Steven Sinofsky said 8 will be able to run on ARM CPUs, which are also used in iDevices.

So I'm curious, would it be possible to run 8 on an iPad, similar to how iDroid works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but it will not be easy. You will probably need to jailbreak your iPad and follow similar procedures when installing Android.